# 拡張ボードのSDカードへの給電のオン、オフ

Tags: spresense

Spresenseのドキュメントに
「Sleep 中の消費電力に関して、拡張ボードに SD カードが挿入されていると SD カードの電源消費分により 約 5 mA ほど消費電流が増加します。」
とあります。

Sleep時の消費電流を減らすために、SDカードへの給電をON,OFFできるArduinoのコードがありましたら教えてください。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_design_ja.html 中の SPRESENSE 拡張ボード回路図を見るに microSD への電源供給は回路的に直結で ON/OFF できるように見えないです。この回路を使う限りでは無理ぽい。

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

あまり参考になるか分かりませんが、速度を気にしないならSPIでSDカードに記録する方法もあります。昔、メインボード用のアドオンボードをユニバーサル基板で自作したことがあります。一応ライブラリも用意しています（ライブラリは個人利用のために作ったものですので、デバッグが不十分な可能性があります。ご使用は自己責任にてお願いします。）

https://github.com/YoshinoTaro/SPISD-for-SpresenseMainboard

sleep中の消費電力は、SDカードへの電源供給ラインの間にスイッチ用のFET等を追加して、GPIOで電源制御すれば抑えられると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にして早速試してみます。